# If column1 is user then insert there otherwise insert in column 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, select

I want to make it so that if `$_SESSION["user"]` exists in `App.Person1` then set that to null otherwise set `App.Person2` to null.

Here is my current query to unassign:

```
update App set App.Person1 = NULL where App.Person1 = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["user"])) . "' and App.ID = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["edit"])) . "' || update App set App.Person2 = NULL where App.Person2 = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["user"])) . "' and App.ID = '" . addslashes(strip_tags($_SESSION["edit"])) . "'"
```

**Problem:** It doesn't seem to update the field with this query

**Example:**

I have three columns here and I am logged in as `Tommy`:

```
App.ID App.Person1 App.Person2
1      Tommy       Green
```

Since Tommy exists in `Person1`, when I click the button, I want it to change to `null`.

Here is another example:

```
App.ID App.Person1 App.Person2
1      Green       Tommy
```

Since `Tommy` doesn't exist in `Person1`, I want `Person2` to change to `null`

**Question:** Is there a solution by using a nested query or case statement that I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: You can do a select query, check what you need with PHP, and then update the desired column with the assistant of php conditions

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  It is hard to tell what you want the code to really do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff posted a full example

Comment: @Yair.R would it be possible for you to post an example of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM App WHERE Person1 = :person1 OR Person2 = :person2';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':person1' $_SESSION["user"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':person2' $_SESSION["user"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
if($stmt->execute() === FALSE){
   Throw new \Exception('could not connect!');
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
   if($row['Person1'] == $_SESSION["user"]) {
        //Do update for person1
   }
   else {
      //Do update for person2
   }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there an easier solution through just mysql? like a nested query or case statement

Comment: There should be, but the query will be ugly and unreadable. Thats why you can use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Is this essentially what you want?

```
update App
    set Person1 = NULL
    where Person1 = $_SESSION["user"];

update App
    set Person2 = NULL
    where Person2 = $_SESSION["user"];
```

Comment: Yes... but I will have to use an `||` statement in PHP to connect the two.. correct?

Comment: I have updated my query in the post... It doesn't seem to work with the `||` statement